# center pinpad div vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center the following div.
I have tried display flex in wrapper and container.
I have searched, read and tried all options listed here but its not working for me :( I'm sure I'm just missing a small detail.

Can anyone help me please.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="display" disabled />

    <div id="pin-pad">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
      <div>Enter</div>
      <div>0</div>
      <div>Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that this can be achieved. The simplest is to just add `flex-flow: column;`.This way instead of horizontally, flex will work vertically - this is going to be the "flow" of the flexbox;

If you want to be centered vertically, try:

```css
#pin-pad {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="pin-pad">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>Enter</div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div>Clear</div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to be aligned in the middle, remove the `align-items: center`;

Comment: Thank you very much but didn't work for me :(
this it my current css:
`
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#display {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  width: 9em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
}

#pin-pad {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4em 4em 4em 4em;
  grid-template-columns: 4em 4em 4em;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  user-select: none;
}
#pin-pad div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 1.25em;`

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this. All I need is to vertically align the wrapper in the center. [link](https://ibb.co/cLSSyX7)

Answer (score 0):

The technique will be the same as centering (vertically and horizontally) the numbers in the number "buttons".

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

As you are aware, this needs to be applied to the parent container for the child to center (vertically and horizontally) correctly.

Noting that the `#wrapper` is just an element to keep the `#display` and `#pin-pad` orientated correctly, you would need to apply the above CSS to the `#container`.

Lastly, to push the height of the `#container` out to full vertical height of the window, use `height: 100vh`.

> See [`<height>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for more information.

---

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pinpad.css" />

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test - Pin Pad</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <input type="text" id="display" disabled />

                <div id="pin-pad">
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>2</div>
                    <div>3</div>
                    <div>4</div>
                    <div>5</div>
                    <div>6</div>
                    <div>7</div>
                    <div>8</div>
                    <div>9</div>
                    <div>Enter</div>
                    <div>0</div>
                    <div>Clear</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

`pinpad.css`

```css
#container {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height:  100vh;
}

#display {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    width: 9em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: center;
}

#pin-pad {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 4em 4em 4em 4em;
    grid-template-columns: 4em 4em 4em;
    grid-gap: 3px;
    user-select: none;
}

#pin-pad div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```